# Getting around "isXmlHttpRequest"?

Tags: zend-framework, curl

I have a chunk of code blocking me from doing a curl call to an endpoint:

```
if($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

How can I alter my curl call so that the request is seen as an XmlHttpRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the problem for me:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest", "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", "__RequestVerificationToken: ".rand(100, 100000)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea.
If you are sure this is an Ajax request, you can try adding:

```
$_SERVER ['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Comment: It needs to come from the clients side. So something in my POST must ultimately result in this thing thinking its an AJAX request.